# Consulta SQL comparando dois campos da mesma tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela no SQL Server e estou com dificuldade em fazer uma consulta.

Tenho uma tabela como esta:

```
alunos

ra     nome     serie     cod_curso
23     joão     1         EI
23     joão     2         EI
23     joão     3         EI
44     maria    5         EF
44     maria    6         EF
61     jose     10        CCO
32     ana      7         PED
78     ana      8         PED
```

Preciso selecionar o maior valor de `serie` para cada `ra`. O resultado da consulta deve ficar assim:

```
alunos

ra     nome     serie     cod_curso
23     joão     3         EI
44     maria    6         EF
61     jose     10        CCO
78     ana      8         PED
```

Se eu selecionar `MAX(serie)` mas não vai dar certo. Preciso selecionar `MAX(serie)` de acordo com cada `ra`, mas não sei como fazer isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
select ra, nome, cod_curso, max(serie) as serie from alunos group by ra, nome, cod_curso
```

Outra forma sem precisar colocar todos os campos no gruop by:

```
select a1.* from alunos as a1
inner join (
   select a2.ra, max(a2.serie) as serie
   from alunos as a2 group by a2.ra
) a2 on a1.ra = a2.ra and a1.serie = a2.serie
```

Comment: Quando uso essa consulta, retorna este erro:

`Column 'alunos.nome' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: Acrescenta group by ra, nome, cod_curso no final da query.

Comment: Mas se minha tabela tiver 30 colunas vou ter q colocar as 30 no group by?

Comment: Sim, precisaria, mas ver a outra forma que eu coloquei com inner join.

Answer (score 4):

Caso `serie` seja um numero a função `Max()` irá funcionar, não tem mistério.

```
select ra, nome, max(serie), cod_curso from alunos group by  ra, nome, cod_curso
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar: "GROUP BY ra" no final de sua consulta.

O `GROUP BY` vai agrupar sua consulta pela coluna que você quiser, no caso a ra.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se estou confundindo aqui o que vc quer... mas vc tem duas ana com ra diferentes, sendo que vc quer somente uma ***ana*** não daria par asar o group by e ter o resultado que vc mostrou, mas se forem diferente seria mais fácil...
Veja o como fica abaixo para obter o que vc quer...

```
declare @alunos table
(
 ra int,
 nome nvarchar(100),
 serie int,
 cod_curso nvarchar(100)
)

insert into @alunos
values 
(23,'joão',1,    'EI'),
(23,'joão',2,    'EI'),
(23,'joão',3,    'EI'),
(44,'maria',    5,    'EF'),
(44,'maria',    6,    'EF'),
(61,'jose',10,   'CCO'),
(32,'ana', 7,    'PED'),
(78,'ana', 8,    'PED')

select a.* from @alunos a
join(select nome,     max(serie) as serie,    cod_curso from @alunos
        group by nome,  cod_curso
    )d
on d.nome = a.nome
and d.serie = a.serie
and d.cod_curso = a.cod_curso
```

Se for o caso de pegar o maior ra vc pode fazer direto assim..

```
select max(ra) as ra, nome,     max(serie) as serie,    cod_curso from @alunos
group by nome,  cod_curso
```

Ou se a *ana* forem pessoas diferente use

```
select ra, nome,     max(serie) as serie,    cod_curso from @alunos
group by ra, nome,  cod_curso
```